# What does int (*x)[n] = (int (*)[n]) _x mean?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am starting to learn `C` and dealing with pointers at the moment. Just came across this and got confused about what it means or does.

`int (*x)[n] = (int ( * )[n]) _x`

I know the expression on the left side means that `x` is a pointer to an array of ints of size `n`. Not sure about the one on the right and what the assignment evaluates to.

Would appreciate if someone could simply clear my mind on this.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: it also means the same, only thing is you are casting `_x` explicitly, which may not be required if it is of same type

Answer (score 0):

The right side casts the variable `_x` to the type `int (*)[n]`, which is a pointer to a variable-length array of n integers.